# Best encryption and decryption algorithm for url

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I need to encrypt and decrypt URLs in my application.

Encryption is a must to bypass censorship. The application currently uses RC4 but its no longer viable nowadays and hopefully there is a better alternative.

A good algorithm should have following characteristics:

1. The hash should be as short as possible 
   Some web filters will block URLs that are greater than 75 characters. A hash shorter than one produced by RC4 would be a good option.
2. The algorithm should be efficient both in terms of memory usage and CPU.
3. The algorithm should be stronger than RC4.
4. PHP & JS implementation of the algorithm should be available.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're actually trying to do - perhaps you could start by explaining your premise? A hash is not a cipher, either.

Comment: Hash: SHA-3, Cipher: AES.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned RC4 which is a stream cipher.  As you said, it is insecure.  It seems odd to use a stream cipher for URLs, but if this is the way you want to go, I would suggest you look at Salsa20.  Google is using it, and there are no patents on it.

If you wanted to go with a block cipher, AES is one of the good compromises between security and speed.  Those are two of the factors that caused it to win the AES competition -- adequate security and very good speed.  I would actually prefer this over Salsa20 unless you really want a stream cipher.

As for keeping the size down, both of the above are fairly compact.  AES, for example, will require 16 byte blocks and will pad out to the even multiple of 16.  So if you have to stay under 75 characters (and assuming 1 character per byte in your encoding) you would have to stay under 64 characters to keep AES from making another block which would make an even 80 bytes.

I suggest compressing the URL first, then encrypting.  You should be able to squeeze a lot of data into 72 bytes that way.  Just remember to compress, then encrypt.  If you encrypt first, the cipher text is pretty impervious to compression.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to encrypt and decrypt URLs in my application.

Can I suggest [an alternative solution to URL parameter encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)?

> Encryption is a must to bypass censorship. The application currently uses RC4 but its no longer viable nowadays and hopefully there is a better alternative.

Use HTTPS. [Avoid client-side Javascript cryptography in the browser](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/). With the new [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) certificate authority, HTTPS is free and easier than ever.